# How to loop through an int to determine the "," for dollars

Tags: android, string, int

I have int values I take from seekBars, and display them in a TextView via ValueOf(). I am wondering if there is a way to implement a method to turn 1000 to 1,000 or 100000 to 100,000 without endless comparing and if statements. or point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: check the class `DecimalFormat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the NumberFormat class to convert the numbers based on the user's locale:

```
int i = 1000000;
String str = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().format(i);
```

`Output: 1,000,000`